# Texture mapping a cone in opengl

Tags: c, opengl, graphics

I am trying to texture map a cone in opengl. Here's my code.

```
glPushMatrix();
float radius=1;
float r=1;
float h=1;
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texSet[2]);
float t,s;
float i=0.05;

for(s=0.0;s<1.0;s+=i)
{
    for(t=0.0;t<=1.0;t+=i)
    {       
        float r=((h-t)/h)*radius;
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glTexCoord2f(s,t);
        glVertex3f(r*cos(2*M_PI*s),t,r*sin(2*M_PI*s));
        glTexCoord2f(s+i,t);
        glVertex3f(r*cos(2*M_PI*(s+i)),t,r*sin(2*M_PI*(s+i)));
        glTexCoord2f(s+i,t+i);
        glVertex3f(r*cos(2*M_PI*(s+i)),(t+i),r*sin(2*M_PI*(s+i)));
        glTexCoord2f(s,t+i);
        glVertex3f(r*cos(2*M_PI*s),(t+i),r*sin(2*M_PI*s));
    }
    glEnd();
}

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopMatrix();
```

I am not getting a proper result. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You need to provide more information with your question. For example, tell us what is *wrong* with your "result"?

Comment: GL_POLYGON constrains the geometry to be convex. The hull of a cone is definitely concave, i.e. you can't use a GL_POLYGON for it. A GL_TRIANGLE_FAN with the hub at the tip of the cone is far better suited for this task.

Comment: @NicolBolas My texture is not mapping to the cone.Instead i am getting  a wired cone

Comment: Not enough context.  Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @datenwolf You are right! Thank you..it works with GL_TRIANGLE_FAN

Answer (score 0):

First thing: `glBegin` and `glEnd` should be called the same amount of times. Your current loops call `glBegin` several times in t-loop, but `glEnd` just once in s-loop.

```
for(s=0.0;s<1.0;s+=i)
{
    for(t=0.0;t<=1.0;t+=i)
    {       
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        ...
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

If you use GL_POLYGON any vertices listed within begin/end form up one polygon. So if you want/need to stick to it - call begin/end within t-loop.

On the other hand, you can create cone with just GL_TRIANGLES, where each 3 vertices form a triangle. In that case you could could do begin/end only once outside s-loop.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); in function. When loop, it load texture and remove it so you can see it 1 second :))